# Connect to Azure Service Bus with Python

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus

I have a mixed (C#, Python) system communicating asynchronously through Azure Service Bus queues. Everything was working fine but now I'm getting strange error messages in my Python consumer (which is basically a copy and paste from: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues/). In particular, the line

`msg = bus_service.receive_queue_message('myqueue', peek_lock=False)`

always results in a `could not convert string to float: max-age=31536000` error - the queue is accessed though (in fact, I can see in Azure that the message gets actually off the queue), and I already tried with different types of payload (the original Json based I was using and simple string now). Strangest of all, was working fine. Does anybody got a similar experience?

Comment: Please try using the latest major version 7.0.0 https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering my own question in case somebody stumbles into the same problem. My requirements.txt file was not up to date with the latest Python Azure module (of course, I checked the wrong Python env and so I was "sure" it wasn't that :-)). Once I updated the dependencies, things started working again.